# Options/suggestions for emphasizing or making parts of a document stand out?

Tags: typography, text, page-layout

I'm trying to come up with a scheme for emphasizing parts of a document. I want something more then just using an italic font as it could be a couple of paragraphs.

Other parts of my document have **strong** emphasis as shown in the example below for a *Requirement*. I need another way to emphasize text; it needs to stand out, but not as strongly as this. Does anyone have suggestions on how to make this happen?

While I will eventually implement this in LaTeX, I'm not looking for LaTeX implementation—that I can do on my own. I am looking for different examples of how this may be done.

---

[image: Example of strong emphasis]

Comment: Just to be clear... you want a gentler highlight than "Requirement..." _only,_ or are you also asking about the rest? As i see it, "Requirement.." is the headline for the content of a box. From the top of my head, it seems you are really asking for suggestions to a document structure and hierarchy?

Comment: Are you using TeX or something similar to do this? [There's a Stack for that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). It strikes me that your need may be met by not using bold for the box header.

Comment: As mentioned by Andrew are you asking how to do this in TeX or are you asking for an answer on how to design it better?

Comment: While I am eventually going to do this in LaTeX, I'm not looking for LaTeX examples. I'm just interested in ways of different ways setting text apart but still looks professional and doesn't distract.

Comment: You've already placed the title in a box. That, alone, is enough to differentiate it. So go ahead and use bold elsewhere. Or keep that bold, and still use bold elsewhere. There is no rule that you can only bold text in one section. FYI, this question is pretty broad at the moment. We really need to see the entire document and understand what specific text you need to emphasize.

Comment: Do you mind editing your question to reflect that information

Comment: @Gramps I've edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Document hierarchies can be tricky, and it is almost a science in itself.

There are of course some basic rules of thumb. It seems to me that what you are making is a technical document with the traditional divisions of chapters, subchapters etc.

**Generally**

- Use as few font families as possible
- Use as few fonts as possible
- Use as few font sizes as possible
- Be careful of too much use of colours
- Use indents
- Mirror the content hierarchy in the table of contents
- Do not try to highlight "everything", it gets messy
- Be generous with whitespace - this is also a way of supporting the
  hierarchy

So I am just going to show you a basic model that I use myself for technical documents, and I will try to argue the choices I made.

### Table of contents:

Reflects the structure of the document, use the same grayscale/colour as the respective headings and subheadings. *If you use colour for headings, be very very careful;* do not overdo colours, as it will be distracting. You want it to be *wayfinding*, not make it look like a children's book. I cannot stress this enough.

[image]

### Headings hierarchy:

The use of bold, italic indent and grayscale (or gentle use of colour) helps a hierarchical structure. Keep the drill-down-headings to a minimum. In my experience four levels is usually enough, and when I get to heading 4, it is often a list-outs with short, simple content. After that, bullet points, tables, illustrations, images, quotes and possibly highlighted boxes will do the job. There is no reason to overdo the hierarchical structure. Of course, if heading 5 and 6 are really needed, make them. But make sure that is an informed choice.

[image]

### Highlight box:

So, as per your example, I am going to assume that sometimes, you need to highlight something extra. Let us call it tip-boxes: short bits of content that really needs to stand out and capture the attention of the reader who quickly flick through your document. **Use them sparingly.** When you have a coloured/grayscale box to highlight, you *do not need to highlight it more* with bold/italic etc, nor do you have to use strong outlines on the box, shadows or other effects. The box is enough. Personally, I would probably go for a grayscale or a *very* soft colour, but consider this only a quick and dirty example:

[image]

Your highlight box should not be too big! if it takes up more than a few paragraphs, you might want to reconsider wether it should be in a highlight box at all, or if you can divide some of the content out of the box. The importance of the highlight box should also be reflected in the table of contents.

[image]

Be generous with space! Space creates and backs up a hierarchy, makes it easier to read, to scan, and to mentally sort.

[image]

---

**Edit:**

- Start every heading 1 on a new page.

Consider if you *really have to* use numerical identification for chapters and sub-headings. In my opinion, *they are rarely as helpful as they seem.* There are a few alternatives:

- Skip them entirely, you will have page numbers
- Put them at the end of the heading instead ("Data storage
  1.1.1............... 12")
- Make them a little more transparent than the rest of the heading
- Keep the numbers on chapters only, *or* on the top three hierarchical elements.

Often, the idea of those reference numbers, are that it makes it easier to refer to in other publications:

"as John Smith highlights, (My Document Name, 1.1.2. Data storage) bla bla"

but just as often are references like this quite normal:

"as John Smith highlights, (My Document Name, p.12)".

Or sometimes

"as John Smith highlights, (My Document Name, ch. 1, p. 12)"

Comment: While this is an excellent answer (+1) I believe his question is asking how to do this in TeX.

Comment: Ah, I did not interpret it as such; I merely answered the visual tools and effects.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with that but I think the OP is asking for how to do it in TeX possibly.

Comment: Fair enough; my knowledge of LaTex markup is not good enough to answer that. Let us hope someone with more knowledge can answer/translate to that. If the Q is about LaTex, maybe the heading should be altered to "LaTex: how to create emphasis for document hierarchies" or somesuch.

Comment: ... @Gramps and hopefully, my answer will be useful to someone someday anyway :)

Comment: This is a good response. While I am eventually going to do this in LaTeX, I'm not looking for LaTeX examples; I can do that on my own. I'm just looking for ideas on how to set text apart.

Comment: I think it is a good overview. One Law Of Typography Which Should Never Be Broken (and sometimes broken if it suits you) is "never double emphasize." The idea really being "why do i think that adding more pieces of flair is proper?"

Comment: @horatio :D that is essentially my point. Jeremy: Good to hear. I sort of went all-out in including lots of elements, just in case. Of course, my examples are quick-and-dirty, and the content and context _may_ have additional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using different hierarchical methods to make that text stand out.

1. Use different sizes of font.
2. Use a different colour, making sure to create contrast with background, but within the colour palette that you're using.
3. Use all caps for headers.
4. Use all of the above.
5. Consider adding imagery to support your statements.